# How to set value for NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED =0 in MAC

Tags: api, postman

i have to run API files which i have created in Postman and imported to VS-Code . But after setting the repo when i am trying to run it is getting failed .

Hence for that i need to set up the environment value for  `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED =0` in mac . But i am not sure how to do .

Any input please ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 - Mac
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 - windows
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 - linux
```

its just environment variable